# How do i open a php file from java swing program?

Tags: java, php, html, swing

How do i open a php file from a java swing program with the click of a button?
I have a project which requires the help page to be opened in a browser and written in php.

Comment: you can open it from default user browser.or you can use javafx browser or swing browser library.and written in php ?have you hosted it in a server?

Comment: You'd need to be a lot more specific and also show us what you've tried already. Is the help page deployed locally? If it is, why does it have to be written in php? And why is it dynamic anyways?

Comment: It is more of a school project which is to apply php somewhere.I have done php in netbeans and so is my swing program. I would like to open URL http://localhost/project/hi.php in my browser on the click of a jButton from the jFrame

Comment: @NithaChalil if you write it in php you better host it online server.because clients don't like/need to install local server.

Comment: Yup, thanks alot...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://localhost/help.php"));
```